# ActiveX Control in IE Doesn't Detect Keystrokes

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, firebreath

i had an issue while using activex with firebreath on internet explorer with backspace button not being fired on textbox, instead the browser goes back

Answer (score 1):

If your plugin doesn't have the focus it won't get the keystrokes first and the browser will handle them.  Even if it does get the keystrokes you may need to do something to make sure they aren't passed back to the browser as the backspace key on IE has long been a shortcut for "back"